# Setting up Rails 6 with PostgreSQL in AWS Cloud9 (c9)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-6, cloud9

I'm trying to set up Rails 6 with a PostgreSQL database in AWS Cloud9. Here are the steps I've taken.

I set up a new environment in cloud9 with a Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS platform.

Then I install the latest version of rails with `gem install rails`

Then I check the rails version with `rails -v` which returns `Rails 6.1.4.1`

Then I create a new rails app with `rails new my_app -d postgresql` However, this returns the error in the build log at the end of this post.

Here are some of my trouble shooting attempts.

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53321162/pg-gem-wont-install-in-rails-app-gemextbuilderror-error-failed-to-build) suggestion `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` followed by `gem install pg` which resulted in an error telling me to install yarn which I did via the learn enough to be dangerous tutorial `source <(curl -sL https://cdn.learnenough.com/yarn_install)`. Then I did `rails new my_app -d postgresql` again resulting in a few warnings about webpacker and an error about `http-proxy-middleware@2.0.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module` but it seemed to work so I navigate to the new app and do `rails db:migrate` but this results in the following error message `rails aborted! ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`.

```
      create  
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  .gitattributes
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/ubuntu/environment/my_app/.git/
      create  package.json
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
      create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/javascript/channels/consumer.js
      create  app/javascript/channels/index.js
      create  app/javascript/packs/application.js
      create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
      create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
      create  app/models/application_record.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
      create  app/assets/images
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  bin/spring
      create  bin/yarn
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/cable.yml
      create  config/puma.rb
      create  config/spring.rb
      create  config/storage.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/cors.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_1.rb
      create  config/initializers/permissions_policy.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/master.key
      append  .gitignore
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
      create  public/apple-touch-icon.png
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  tmp
      create  tmp/.keep
      create  tmp/pids
      create  tmp/pids/.keep
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor
      create  vendor/.keep
      create  test/fixtures/files
      create  test/fixtures/files/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/channels/application_cable/connection_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  test/system
      create  test/system/.keep
      create  test/application_system_test_case.rb
      create  storage
      create  storage/.keep
      create  tmp/storage
      create  tmp/storage/.keep
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
      remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_1.rb
         run  bundle install
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Fetching rake 13.0.6
Installing rake 13.0.6
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
Using i18n 1.8.10
Fetching minitest 5.14.4
Installing minitest 5.14.4
Using tzinfo 2.0.4
Using zeitwerk 2.4.2
Using activesupport 6.1.4.1
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubi 1.10.0
Fetching mini_portile2 2.6.1
Installing mini_portile2 2.6.1
Using racc 1.5.2
Using nokogiri 1.12.4 (x86_64-linux)
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.12.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
Using actionview 6.1.4.1
Using rack 2.2.3
Fetching rack-test 1.1.0
Installing rack-test 1.1.0
Using actionpack 6.1.4.1
Using nio4r 2.5.8
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.5
Installing websocket-driver 0.7.5 with native extensions
Using actioncable 6.1.4.1
Using globalid 0.5.2
Using activejob 6.1.4.1
Using activemodel 6.1.4.1
Using activerecord 6.1.4.1
Using marcel 1.0.1
Using mini_mime 1.1.1
Using activestorage 6.1.4.1
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailbox 6.1.4.1
Using actionmailer 6.1.4.1
Using actiontext 6.1.4.1
Fetching public_suffix 4.0.6
Installing public_suffix 4.0.6
Fetching addressable 2.8.0
Installing addressable 2.8.0
Fetching bindex 0.8.1
Installing bindex 0.8.1 with native extensions
Fetching msgpack 1.4.2
Installing msgpack 1.4.2 with native extensions
Fetching bootsnap 1.8.1
Installing bootsnap 1.8.1 with native extensions
Using bundler 1.17.2
Fetching byebug 11.1.3
Installing byebug 11.1.3 with native extensions
Fetching regexp_parser 2.1.1
Installing regexp_parser 2.1.1
Fetching xpath 3.2.0
Installing xpath 3.2.0
Fetching capybara 3.35.3
Installing capybara 3.35.3
Fetching childprocess 3.0.0
Installing childprocess 3.0.0
Fetching ffi 1.15.4
Installing ffi 1.15.4 with native extensions
Fetching jbuilder 2.11.2
Installing jbuilder 2.11.2
Fetching rb-fsevent 0.11.0
Installing rb-fsevent 0.11.0
Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.1
Installing rb-inotify 0.10.1
Fetching listen 3.7.0
Installing listen 3.7.0
Using method_source 1.0.0
Fetching pg 1.2.3
Installing pg 1.2.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby -I /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210910-9968-sc88vh.rb
extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-pg
        --without-pg
        --enable-windows-cross
        --disable-windows-cross
        --with-pg-config
        --without-pg-config
        --with-pg_config
        --without-pg_config
        --with-pg-dir
        --without-pg-dir
        --with-pg-include
        --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
        --with-pg-lib
        --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/pg-1.2.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/pg-1.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/pg-1.2.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (1.2.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.2.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  pg
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
Could not find gem 'pg (~> 1.1)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
       rails  webpacker:install
Could not find gem 'pg (~> 1.1)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```